# Is WM_IME_REPORT obsolete?

Tags: windows, ime

I can't find the Microsoft documentation for the WM_IME_REPORT window procedure message anymore. Has it been obsoleted? We handle the WM_IME_REPORT message in our window procedure, but during testing, it never seems to be received anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of [SendIMEMessageEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ime/nf-ime-sendimemessageexa), whitch returns the `IMESTRUCT` structure and has then `WM_IME_REPORT` message, is marked obsolete.

Windows have switched to TSF instead of IME, so this message seems be abandoned.